# Unique user IDs of users who shared a link.

Tags: facebook, api

I have the Facebook share button on my website. I want to be able to store in my database the unique user IDs of all the users who clicked that share button (and shared the link on their wall of course.) Does Facebook allow us to access this Information about users?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. Sharing a link doesn't give the option to release user information as this is how it's designed. The only way to release user information is for user to grant access to an application you own.

Comment: I don't understand why that is :(. It seems like such a trivial thing - user IDs are publicly available information. Why isn't it available for the site that hosts the Share button?